# Were the BOSS Linux update servers hacked in 2015?

Tags: government, security, india, hacking

The [Hackology Blog](https://blog.drhack.net/indian-government-army-navy-hacked-boss/) claims that update servers for [BOSS Linux](https://www.bosslinux.in/) were hacked in 2015, eventually allowing access to Indian military and government servers.

This website claims that:

1. Hackers infected the update servers and repositories which means they could backdoor any software installed by a BOSS user.
2. Tools leaked from the [NSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Security_Agency) were used to exploit these servers.
3. Through the repositories they infected every user account.

Is it true such an attack was successfully carried out on the Indian government?